# Sqlite with Django framework table update/insert

Tags: python, django-models

Currently I am using SQLite with Django framework.I want to flow data from table1 to table2. The logic is, if data already present in table2, then it will update the table2 else will insert. I know how to insert or update data but not sure how to check the logic that if the data is already there in Table 2 or not. Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to select data from table 1

   `qs = YourModelTable1.objects.all()`
2. Then select or find data in table 2 if exist than update, for example:

   ```
   for data in qs:
       id = data.id
       obj = YourModelTable2.objects.get(id=id)
       if obj.exists():
            obj.update(field1=value1, field1=value2, ...)
            obj.save()

       else:
            obj = data
            obj.save()
   ```

Comment: Really thanks for your quick response. Just for a clarification, both the tables hold composite primary key(total 5 columns common for both). Suppose id1,id2,id3,id4,id5 are common for both.Then how to check?

Comment: just add coma in args when you get the obj, eg: `obj = YourModelTable2.objects.get(id=id, id1=otherid, id2=otherid1, ...)`

Comment: really thanks for your help.Could you please explain the following in your code?  tmp = obj.exclude(pk=id)

Comment: really thanks for your help.for composite pk, I have done the following.Is it ok? tmp = obj.exclude(pk=PROJECT_NAME,pk=ACCNT_NAME,pk=APP_NAME,pk=SPRINT_NO,pk=RELEASE_NAME)

Comment: but if I use as tmp = obj.exclude(pk=PROJECT_NAME,pk=ACCNT_NAME,pk=APP_NAME,pk=SPRINT_NO,pk=RELEASE_NAME), then having some Syntax error:( ... If I use like this > tmp = obj.exclude(pk=PROJECT_NAME,ACCNT_NAME,APP_NAME,SPRINT_NO,RELEASE_NAME), then also having syntax error

Comment: if it didn't work you can try another way to update data like `obj.update(active=True, otherfield='Value', ...)

Comment: Hi I am getting the below error after running the code - NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: try use python pdb and look which save that raise the error, it's like your obj is empty before you saving. If the problem still didn't solve you may create new question with providing your actual code.